# How to change the area surround a menu button to make it clickable?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the Shape5.com Corporate Response Joomla template and been asked to change the behavior of the Menu buttons, so that as you mouse over to the button as soon as its background highlights, that it is clickable. The way it works now, you have to move the mouse further within the Menu's title where it changes the cursor from pointer to hand so it is clickable. If the user clicks on this before it changes to a hand, it doesn't do anything because the click isn't active yet. I've been asked to change this so the moment it has highlighted the background that menu is clickable. Here is a demo of the web page:
http://www.shape5.com/demo/corporate_response/

I'm not sure how to proceed on this. Is this something which can be controlled by CSS? Or is this controlled by JavaScript? When the mouse is moved from within the surround area of the Menu button and the highlighted background changes, is that a function only of the JavaScript? Or is that CSS?

If it's in JavaScript, how do I go about making a change to understand how this works, does it use pixels to define a image map of sorts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late on but I wrestled with this for some time and resolved it and I wanted to make sure others could find the answer.

Simply put in custom.css in your template you can use css

```
active a {
color: #xxxxxx: !important; 
}
```

This means no messing about with onclick functions and core template.

Answer (score 0):

Original:

```
<span class="s5_level1_span1">
 <span class="s5_level1_span2">
   <a href="javascript:;">Tutorials</a>
 <span class="S5_parent_subtext" onclick="window.document.location.href="javascript:;"">Find Help Here</span>
 </span>
</span>
```

New

```
<a href="javascript:;">
   <span class="s5_level1_span1">
   <span class="s5_level1_span2">
   Tutorials
   <span class="S5_parent_subtext" onclick="window.document.location.href="javascript:;"">Find Help Here</span>
   </span>
   </span>
</a>
```

Wrap the  around the spans as opposed to the text, that'll expand the clickable area.

Comment: Thanks, Pat, how did you find this code? I don't see it in View Source HTML in Google Chrome. Were you using Inspect Element?

Comment: Firebug - https://getfirebug.com/ (for Firefox & Chrome) - exceedingly useful tool - a must have !

Answer (score 0):

Mouse button click is a browser event, and you can "hook" to it using javascript, that means you can write a function in javascript to do something on click.

In your case, that function is attributed to the text of each menu item, not to the item itself. You have to move `onclick` attribute from `<span>` with `class="S5_parent-subtext"`, to `<li>` with `class="mainParentBtn"`, for each menu item. But since it's a joomla template, I presume HTML is being generated in PHP, so you will have to find where it is being generated and change it. And I suppose you have to know at least a little bit of PHP and the architecture of joomla to do that...

Comment: Yes, this Joomla template uses Vertex developed by Shape5 and a Flex Menu system in addition to their Joomla template. I will have to dig through all this to find out how to is putting this together to change it. I also see one reference to S5_parent_subtext if I do a view of HTML source of the page, so I'm not sure how you arrived at getting this code yet.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, right click your text and press "Inspect element". (This is available in some other browsers, but not in IE.) Now, buy hovering over HTML in console that opens, you'll see them highlighted on the page. That's how you can find where to put the `onclick` attribute.